# Show different content based on url segement

Tags: channel-entries, relationships, conditionals

Sorry if my title is a little confusing. Here is my dilemma...

I have a product category page with different products. I'm trying to figure out a way to say {if segment_3} show the product specific information. Right now I'm having no luck. I'm new to EE, so I'm sure some of you vets this will be easy. Here is my code so far.

```
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="1" limit="15"}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product-wrapper">
                <div class="product-card">
                    <a href="{segment_2}/{url_title}" class="product-img-wrapper"><img src="{card_img}" alt=""></a>
                    <h4>{title}</h4>
                    {short_description}
                    <div class="btn-container">
                        <a href="{segment_2}/{url_title}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">View Product</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div> <!-- End Row -->
</div> <!-- End Container -->
</section>

{if segment_3}
{embed="products/product-detail"}
{/if}
```

Comment: Can you also share code of `product-detail` page?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is accurate; **products/product-detail** should be embedded if **segment_3** has a value. Perhaps you need to pass data into the embedded template?

Something like:

```
{embed="products/product-detail" product_id="{segment_3}"}
```

Then in **products/product-detail** you would reference the passed data like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="{embed:product_id}"}
```

That might be what you are looking for, but without seeing the contents of **products/product-detail** there is no way to be sure.

Hope that helps.